# Node Modular Architecture

Tags: node.js, architecture, npm

I am building a nodejs application that is fairly large now. In an attempt to avoid a monolithic node application I have gone down the architectural route of a more modular system breaking out several components into separate npm modules. These are published using npm and installed in the dependent modules. I have about 6 different modules (which I would want to break out in to more) and now it has become difficult to manage the packages.

**The problems** are:

1. There is nested dependency so if I change module A and module B depends on module A and module C depends on module B, then when I update module A I need to publish a new version of it, which then means I need to update it in module B, which means I also need to publish of that and then finally I need to install that new version in module A ... you can see where that might be a pain. What's more the updating of the versions in all the package.json is manual and so error prone, and waiting for each publish is time consuming.
2. Modules can share npm dependencies and so sometimes conflicts occur when packages get updated. The more modules the higher the chance of conflict.

**The benefits** are that we have a very modular system where libraries can be reused easily and there is a clear hierarchy of modules enforced as there can't be any circular dependencies.

**Possible solutions** are:

1. **Monolith** - To manage the dependencies as a single app in a single repository with each module just becoming a services. This means that only one update is necessary and all the module apis will be in sync. However, referencing the libraries in the code might be a bit of a pain (as I believe they will have to be referenced relative to the local file), I am not sure how a structural hierarchy between the modules can be enforced and code reuse will be harder with modules outside the repository.
2. **Microservices** - To make each module a micro service. This maintains all the benefits of the modular system, but I am concerned that it will add a lot of complexity to the build and managing all the services will become a full time job in itself.
3. **Keep going** - Work out a way to keep the current architecture but remove the trouble of pushing updates etc. Maybe scripts to update versions and shrinkwrap to ensure correct dependencies. I think this would both be difficult and would potentially lead it to being a monolithic system of a different variety.

Option 1 seems the most manageable to me but I don't want to lose the modular structure if I don't have to.

This is quite a broad question, but any suggestions/advice/comments would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Manually updating package.json seems to be the big issue, why not simply do a "moduleA" : "*"?  Then you can make sure to do a npm install in your build/deploy script. Assuming that things didn't break which should be verified by your continuous integration server before you deploy

Comment: Also in case, you have updated A and B but want C to use old version of B. You can use npm shrinkwrap.

Comment: Do the npm modules you currently have ever need to run stand-alone?

Comment: no, they don't need to run by themselves, but they are used in other projects, such as support tools

Comment: @RahatMahbub thanks for the suggestion, and we are allowing minor changes in our config, but it still requires rerunning each build to incorporate the updated module

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend going for solution 2.

- Break down all your code in small modules.
- Implement loose-coupling with event emitters.
- there is no added value in storing each module as its own npm package, unless they are used stand-alone outside of your application.

The two problems you have described are simply caused by the fact that each module is independently stored as an npm package.

#### Benefits

- Problem 1 is solved as you don't need to manage npm packages in `package.json` anymore.
- Problem 2 is solved as you only have one `package.json` managing all the dependencies
- You still have a clean modular structure thanks to usage of separate node.js modules.

#### Example implementation

A few months ago, I refactored a monolithic node.js app using these principles, and it really eased the maintenance, and didn't add overhead to the build process.

The pattern is the following:

main module is `app.js`

```
var sys = require('sys')
    , events = require('events')
    , UserModel = require('./model/user') // this is a microservice taking care of managing user data
    , Logic = require('./controller/logic')   // this is another microservice doing some work

var App = function (server, app) {

    this.controller = (
        logic: new Logic(this) // "this" is the app instance, it's passed to all microservices, which will benefit from the access to event emitter...
    }
    this.model = {
        new UserModel(this)
    }

    // ...
}

sys.inherits(App, events.EventEmitter)

module.exports = App
```

A microservice looks like this:

```
/**
* Logic functions
* 
* this controller does ...
*
* @constructor
*
*/
function Logic(app) {

    /****************************************
    *
    * Private methods
    *
    ****************************************/

    /**
    * this is a private function in the controller
    * 
    * @private
    */
    function computeSomething () {

        var res = 3

        app.emit('computed', res) // emit event, that can be liseted to by some other modules

        return res
    }


    /****************************************
    *
    * Public methods
    *
    ****************************************/    

    /**
    * 
    * This function can be called directly by the other modules using "app.controller.logic.work()"
    * 
    */
    this.work = function () {

        return 'result is ' + computeSomething()
    }


    /****************************************
    * 
    * Event listeners
    * 
    ****************************************/

    /**
    * listener: event from the app - loose-coupling magic happens thanks to this. Recommended over public functions.
    *
    * @private
    */
    app.on('data-ready', this.work)

}

module.exports = Logic
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of a more elaborate microservice structure that used http messaging but this is nice as it is much more manageable and maintains the dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered different modular structures? The decision of having microservices or a monolith affects how the components communicate with each other, the scalability and deployability of the system, but you will still need to follow best practices in package design. Otherwise you will have the same chain reaction when updating a low level package.

Your current structure of package C depending on package B depending on package A causes difficulties in package management because you need to make too many modifications to lower level packages.

[image: diagram of the current structure]

This type of issue is a sign of too much up-front package design, whereas package design really should be done as you go.

The advantage of your current structure is that it does not have any acylic
dependencies. If you update module B, you know exactly module C is affected,
and nothing changes with module A. It should stay this way.

## Managing Dependencies

*Dependency structure*

There are package design principles that are directly related to the issues you have:

**[The Stable Dependencies Principle](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StableDependenciesPrinciple)**
*Depend in the direction of stability*

Given the original structure `C -> B -> A`, most of your changes should occur in `C` and `A` should not any reason to change.

**[The Stable-Abstractions Principle](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StableAbstractionsPrinciple)**
*A package should be as abstract as it is stable*

Relates to the previous principle. Abstract classes leave out specific implementations, and there are many ways you can do that with Javascript.

If you follow these principles well, you might find that it is not an issue
to have more than three packages, because the lower level packages won't change much.

---

## What should be in a package?

*Package by Feature*

The MVC frameworks so popular these days have a structure that separate controller, model and view into different folders. This structure does not scale very well, and after the project has expanded for a while, it becomes hard to visualize what the project does, how different parts are connected to each other, and it's not very convenient to see all the files related to a particular feature. This approach called *package by layer* does not expand very well.

A better way to organize your packages would be to [Package by Feature](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PackageByFeature). Now layering is not a bad thing, and when you package by feature, you should still have this layered structure.

Comment: So permit me to phrase differently/summarise.  The codebase may require heavy refactoring.  A should have all fairly constant code.  B should have slow moving code and may/may not be independent of A.  C is the module/library that will contain the constantly evolving parts.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to elaborate more on my answer as it may not make much sense as it is.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think it is a good argument to be sensible in what you break out in to it's own module, but there are clear areas that I wanted to keep distinct, like the data access layer from the api, both of which change frequently. I'll have to think about how I can incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: A better principle for deciding what should be in a package is *package by feature*, which is mainly related to achieving a good cohesion in your project. I edited my answer to write about this. Another principle that will be useful to manage dependencies between features is the [Inversion of Control](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a Theoretical Model to solve this issue, and just making some research, a bit of experimentation and a bit of common sense.

**Modular Principles List**

1. The code is physically organized in folders by feature.
2. The code does one, and only one thing, and it does it very well.
3. Each feature can be added or removed anytime because it has no dependencies with other features.
4. All communications with other modules are not made directly. A Sandbox or middleware is used instead.
5. If several modules require a common functionality, they take it from an upper hierarchical semi-immutable () structure.

**Advantages and disadvantages** 
This approach looks for one specific goal: loose coupling. The idea behind is that every module can be implemented on its own, it can be developed and tested individually, and many people can contribute at the same time with features.
Look at WordPress, or node ecosystem. Take this example and move it down to your project.

**One example**

CSS has been a clear example to me of how this modular approach may work. If you have a site with many pages, and many sections in it, and your client wants every section to have a variant of the look and feel, probably you will end up with a few hundreds of CSS definitions in one minified big CSS file.

Governance of that CSS may require variables, preprocessor, PostCSS, Javascript handling.... but the real ting is that you wil never use more than a few CSS definitions on every page.

If all pages can be split into modular types and each type with its own rules, probably you can end up with much more code, but smaller files applied one at the time. Probably you will not need to minify any file because the all have what is needed.

**Folder Structure Proposal**
I am working the idea that all code should be organized the same way.
Main folders:

- core
- extensions
- engines

Inside each a structure like this:
**core**
----- extension-manager
------------ css
------------ img
------------ media
------------ js
------------ view
------------ db
------------ data
------------ aux
------------ config.json
------------ README.txt
------------ settings.txt
----- sandbox
------------ css
------------ img
------------ media
------------ js
------------ view
------------ db
------------ data
------------ aux
------------ config.json
------------ README.txt
------------ settings.txt
----- global
------------ css
------------ img
------------ media
------------ js
------------ view
------------ db
------------ data
------------ aux
------------ config.json
------------ README.txt
------------ settings.txt
**extensions**
----- appointments
------------ css
------------ img
------------ media
------------ js
------------ view
------------ db
------------ data
------------ aux
------------ config.json
------------ README.txt
------------ settings.txt
----- calendar
------------ css
------------ img
------------ media
------------ js
------------ view
------------ db
------------ data
------------ aux
------------ config.json
------------ README.txt
------------ settings.txt
----- promotions
------------ css
------------ img
------------ media
------------ js
------------ view
------------ db
------------ data
------------ aux
------------ config.json
------------ README.txt
------------ settings.txt

Hope these ideas may help, any comments are welcome.