# Node.js and project structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, git

I am working on a new project with Node.js, Express, Socket.io and the MySQL module and being a beginner with those technologies, I have a few questions about structuring the project and good practices.

Right now, my code is structured as follow:

```
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── server.js
├── server.socket.live.js # Socket.io namespace
├── server.database.js # For database configuration and connection pool
├── server.database.resources.js # Model for the 'resources' table
├── server.route.live.js
└── ...
```

For the current state of the project, it works well enough, but the code grows fast and a sole directory will make the code hard to navigate and maintain.

So I've been trying to figure out a way to structure my code with the following rules:

- I need global files that I can include from everywhere (for example: the database and models).
- The routes and other sub-components must be (and are) independant to each other.
- Node must be able to correctly cache each files, so different paths ('./database.js' and '../database.js') are out of the question.
- If possible, avoid requires from parent directories.

With that in mind, I came up with this solution:

```
├── package.json
├── node_modules
|   └── ...
├── server.js
├── server
|   ├── node_modules
|   |   ├── database
|   |   |   ├── package.json
|   |   |   ├── database.js
|   |   |   ├── resources.js
|   |   |   └── ...
|   ├── socket
|   |   ├── live.js # With live subfolder if file grows too big
|   |   └── ...
|   ├── routes
|   |   ├── live.js # With live subfolder if too many sub-routes
|   |   └── ...
```

In theory it works great: with a structure like this I could easily add new "global" modules in server/node_modules, and new routes or socket namespaces, as long as they are independant from each other.

So my question: would that work in practice, or is there a better way to do it? Will Node be able to require the files in server/node_modules with good caching? How do I include the server/node_modules subfolder in my git repository (while still ignoring the root node_modules)?

With many thanks!

Comment: You may want to have only one node_modules at root level. I'd do `server/database/..` rather than `server/node_modules/database/..`

Comment: Related question (probably not a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34895019/node-modular-architecture

Comment: @MehdiElFadil Thanks for your answer. One problem I have with putting the database folder directly in `server/` is that I may want to require it in, say, `server/routes/live/users.js`, leading to something ugly like `require('../../database/resource.js')`. Another problem is caching: with a different require path Node will reload files, and I definitely don't want, for example, two connection pools. Is there a way to make a file 'global' without making another `node_modules`? Why is having two `node_modules` a bad idea in the first place?